# Click, do something, Click again, do something on next; each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have this code:

[image]

```
$('html, body').click(function() {

    $("#content a").each(function(i) {
        $(this).remove(i++);
    });

});
```

And now I must set scrollTop to each next and previous element by click on this page:

[image]

For animate I have this code: (BUT THIS CODE IS BAD!!!)

```
$('#prevPost').on('click', function() {
    var prevPosition = $("a").find('div.private_overlay').parent().prev().offset();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: prevPosition.top
    });
});
```

I need to combine these two codes.

Each element on the page is in `#container a .private_overlay`.

In addition, scrollTop must also work to newly added elements - through another script, which I do not have insight. So I guess must be `.on('click', function() {});` to refresh the DOM.

---

Please, this is exactly what I'm trying to work:

[image]

As you can see, the option "**Delete unnecessary posts.**" working properly. Now I must scripted the NEXT button and PREV button. So that, the script was looking for specific posts. And that **marked currently found** (not all, but one that specifically found). When the script will have a specific post, then must scroll to the post browser window.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
function searchBox() {

    $('body').append('<div id="searchBox"><p style="margin: 0px;"><strong>SearchBox: <span style="font-size: 10px;">(private posts)</span></strong></p> \
<p style="margin: 5px auto; text-align: center"><input id="prevPost" type="button" value="Previous post"></input>   \
<input id="nextPost" type="button" value="Next post"></input></p>   \
<p style="margin: 0px;"><input id="hidePosts" type="checkbox"></input><label for="hidePosts" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Delete unnecessary posts.</label></p></div>');

    $('#searchBox').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        left: '20px',
        bottom: '20px',
        background: 'white',
        color: 'rgb(125, 125, 125)',
        fontSize: '13px',
        border: '1px solid rgb(125, 125, 125)',
        borderRadius: '7px',
        padding: '7px',
        zIndex: '9999',
        boxShadow: '0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
        display: 'none'
    }).fadeIn();

    $('#hidePosts').one('click', function() {
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            $('#content a').not($('a').find('div.private_overlay').parent()).hide();
        });
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#prevPost').on('click', function() {
        return_text('prevpost');
    });

    $('#nextPost').on('click', function() {
        return_text('nextpost');
    });

};
```

Where is `return_text('prevpost');` and `return_text('nextpost');` I have to enter the code.

And my old code to scroll the page:

```
//$('#prevPost').click(function() {
    $('#prevPost').on('click', function() {
        var prevPosition = $("a").find('div.private_overlay').parent().prev().offset();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: prevPosition.top
        });
    });
//});
```

**That's not all!** Pictures are loaded automatically by the unfamiliar script, in real time when user browses the page. So script must find also recently added images - need to refresh DOM.

Comment: Could you elaborate the use case: what shoud the user do / click and what should happen.

Btw. using partial nsfw images is not a good idea for a question.

Comment: Just... Someone **click** on button "**NEXT**", and script gets the location of next item and scrolls to it that the entire page. When someone again **click** on the same button "**NEXT**" the script is looking for the next item. Similarly, I do the same with the "**PREVIOUS**" button. These images are not NSFW, and even if it's there's nothing I can do.

Comment: What do you mean by location of next item? I understood the following: 1) image-set A is loaded, 2) if the user clicks on `button NEXT` image set B is loaded, 3.1) a click on `button PREVIOUS` the previous image-set (in this case A) 3.2) another click on  `button NEXT` will load the next image set (in this case C).
Is this the case? Before loading the next / previous set of images (B) each image of the current set (either C / or A) should be hidden one after another `$(this).remove(i++);` How does the scrollTop comes into play?

Comment: No, these images are loaded automatically by another unknown to me the script. I wrote for myself a little script that searches for images in the class: "`.private_overlay`". and also has these pictures scroll the page - only if you click on **NEXT** or **PREV**.

Comment: Just have to select the **next** or **previous** image. And then **scroll to it**.

Comment: I gave the code from the function of `each();`, because I learning how to find a particular item, one after another.

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me. If you could break it down in smaller problems what you want to learn / understand it would  probably be easier to help.

Comment: When I click `$('#prevPost').on('click', function() {});` in function wants to have a code which finds the item and it selects in the DOM. So I could edit this item: delete, hide, change, stand out and **get the position**. I will take the position of `offset();` something like this: `$("a").find('div.private_overlay').parent().offset();` and will paste here: `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: nextPosition.top });`. Now it needs to work, when I click the button: **NEXT** or **PREV**.

Comment: The script needs to find the next, mark, get position and scroll but on the next item! I totally don't know how to select elements in the DOM.

Comment: I'm trying with the function `$("#content a").find('div.private_overlay').parent().each(function(i) { XXX })`, but it don't really works. I can't select one and the particular item, so what I do **NEXT** and **PREV**.

Comment: +1 for the WF question

Comment: wf question? what this is?